# Zurb Foundation 4: remove top-bar fixed/sticky when in mobile?

Tags: zurb-foundation

What would be the best way to keep the "fixed" and/or "sticky" functionality on Zurb Foundation 4's top-bar in desktop views, but remove for mobile views? Having a fixed top bar is great to have on larger devices, but wastes valuable screen real estate on mobile devices.

I'm actually surprised that it doesn't do this by default (or at least have an option to disable on mobile devices).

My quick solution is as follows:

```
$(function() {
    if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width: 768px)')) {
        $('#header').addClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

There's a probably a more elegant solution though (and one that takes care of screen resizing etc.).

EDIT: re-read my question after and realize it was very unclear. Have updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the .fixed class like so:

```
.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  @media #{$small} {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

This will show the navbar as fixed for views larger than mobile, and it should then be free to scroll for mobile.

Comment: I knew there would be something a little less hacky. Thanks. Will implement and get back here.

Comment: Works like a charm. Note of course that if you're unfortunately not using SCSS (not an option for this particular site), then not all browsers will recognize nested media queries so you'll have to split the media query out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer is too obvious, but have you tried on the media query for the mobile devices?

```
.top-bar {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I still need the top bar to show (as it has navigation in it), but don't want it fixed on mobile devices (i.e. show when at the top of the page, but have it scroll out of view as you scroll down).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is more elegant but I think I would use **.hide-for-small**  **.show-for-small** as appears in some elements on the foundation templates, I know that it implies repetition, but hey, it's maybe an opportunity for a more mobile friendly layout for the top-bar. Hope it helps.

Comment: Again, want the top bar still visible, just don't want it fixed for mobile displays only for desktop displays. @jameswilliamiii provided an answer that does that (although my original solution worked, it isn't as clean as his).

Comment: I read @jameswilliamiii 's comment but that's not what I'm saying... I mention the thing about repetition because on the templates that zurb provides they declare the same section twice the first one with **.hide-for-small** and the second one with **.show-for-small** so you get two slightly different top-bars

Comment: Okay. Unless you're referring to implementing with client-side scripting, I'd say James' solution is much better. What template are you specifically referring to at http://foundation.zurb.com/templates.php?

Comment: [Foundation HTML Templates](http://foundation.zurb.com/templates.php) in specific marketing or workspace have this feature, of course is client-side